# Find value in many tables, then act on first blank row within matched table

Tags: vba, excel

**Background**: I am writing a macro that copies information from a change log into the matched row within a master file made of several sheets which each contain one table.  I have the changes written and working, but need to also include a procedure for when the change request is to add a new row.  I have a list in Col A that matches with the request, so I need to search for a matched Col A value within the file, then go to the first blank row in the table (there is a lot of empty space still held within the tables), then copy over the relevant information.

```
Function AddMatch(LOBID As String) As Range
Dim arrSheets, s As Worksheet, f As Range
Dim addr1 As String
arrSheets = Array("Sheet names all go here")
For Each s In arrSheets
    Set s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(s)
    Set f = s.Columns("A").Find(LOBID, Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        addr1 = f.Address()
        Do
            Set AddMatch = f.EntireRow 
            Exit Function
            Set f = s.Columns("A").Find(LOBID, f, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While f.Address() <> addr1
    End If
Next s
Set AddMatch = Nothing
End Function
```

I have this function which finds me the row within the sheets where LOBID is a match.  It may be overcomplicated, but I used the same function with two criteria for another action so it was an easy copy-paste.  I need to act upon the first blank row within the table where that match was found, which is where I'll be adding the new information (copied from the change log).

This returns the first row with a match in Col A.

```
Set destRNG = AddMatch(CStr(changeWS.Cells(i, "A")))
```

I have a feeling there's a very simple addition to get me from this row to the first blank within the table, but I keep getting a Method 'Range' of object'_Global' error on just about everything I've tried.  Is there a simpler way to do this?  Thank you in advance for your help.

**FOLLOW-UP:**  Trying to copy a range from the change log to the new row.  This throws a Method 'Range' of object'_Global' error, not sure how to adjust it to work.

```
rw.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10)) = changeWS.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10))
```

Comment: You should be able to loop down the rows of the table until you hit a blank row - you can use `Application.Counta()` to count the number of values in a row.

Comment: I can do both separately just fine - find a match and find the blank row.  I'm stuck connecting the two, where I will only go to the first blank row of the table in the sheet where the matched value is found.  Any tips on writing that process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub Tester()
Dim rw As Range
    Set rw = FirstEmptyRow("AAA")
    If Not rw Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Found empty row on " & rw.Parent.Name, rw.Address()
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not found..."
    End If

End Sub



Function FirstEmptyRow(LOBID As String) As Range
    Dim arrSheets, s, rv As Range

    arrSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    For Each s In arrSheets
        Set s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(s)
        'any match on this sheet?
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(LOBID, s.Columns("A"), 0)) Then
            Set rv = s.Rows(2) 'start here and work down...
            Do While Application.CountA(rv) > 0
                Set rv = rv.Offset(1, 0)
            Loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next s

    Set FirstEmptyRow = rv
End Function
```

EDIT:

```
rw.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10)) = changeWS.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10))
```

Here you have a problem because `Cells()` without a worksheet qualifier always points to the ActiveSheet, so you're essentially trying to create a range across multiple sheets, hence the error.

```
rw.Range(rw.Cells(1, 1), rw.Cells(1, 10)).Value = _
  changeWS.Range(changeWS.Cells(i, 1), changeWS.Cells(i, 10)).Value
```

would be more correct, but I would prefer this type of approach:

```
rw.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 10).Value = changeWS.Cells(i, 1).resize(i, 10).Value
```

Comment: Tim, you helped me so well the last time I had a similar question on a different part of this project and you've done it again!  This framework is exactly what I need to finish up this task.  Thank you immensely for the assistance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Update your question with your follw-up - code in comments is difficult to read